# Disable One-Page Checkout in OpenCart

Tags: php, checkout, opencart

How can I disable OnePage Checkout in OpenCart?

Version 1.5.x comes with it in the default template and I would rather not use it as we want to have step by step pages and not use Ajax (speed/page views and process serves our needs better) for our customers.

Comment: As far as I know the system is stuck - you need to complete edit the theme and controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to remove the one-page setup, but you'll have to do a very good work on the template (the checkout folder contains all steps). You will need personalized controllers as well. The built-in checkout page uses jQuery and Ajax to gathering all the information necessary in only one page, to send everything together when the customer clicks "confirm".

Once you don't want to use ajax, you will have to send the information from one page to the next using post requests, putting then in hidden `<input>`'s and/or in `$_SESSION` variable. Anyway, you will have some problems with the countries and locations, since OpenCart retrieves then via ajax.

Actually, some time ago I've found some templates on ThemeForest and other sites that implemented what you want, but I don't know if they are available anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; do you what templates they are? This is funny; Magento (as bad as it is) gives you the option for OnePage checkout or for normal (flow step by step) based checkout.

Comment: Since there is no direct solution to this; although I suggest the core team getting on this (I realise it can be logistical issues but look at Magento/Venda Commerce/ Frescha/ Cube Cart/ATG Commerce etc.. One Page or Split is default an admin option.. I will mark this as close to as we are breaking it into session and inputs.

Answer (score -1):

I would actually recommend you use something like [Uber Checkout](http://opencartguru.com/uber-checkout) which while its still a short checkout process, is better visually as you don't have the panels that are standard in 1.5.X. If you're wanting to completely rewrite it to work like the old checkout system, well in theory it's already there, you just need to rewrite the controllers for the various steps to output full pages rather than JSON and put in validations through each step to make sure previous steps have been completed

Comment: Thanks for the comment - Uber Checkout is not currently offering split eCommerce pages.

Comment: No I realise that, but it does make it visually more appealing since it shows all the details without having to click backwards and forwards through panels which is why I thought I'd suggest it